# How to install perl module on RHEL?

Tags: perl, module, rhel7

I need to install perl-Expect, so, I executed:

```
#  yum install -y perl-Expect
Error: Package: perl-Expect-1.21-14.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(IO::Pty) >= 1.03
Error: Package: perl-Expect-1.21-14.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(IO::Tty)
```

Okay, I need to install perl(IO::Pty)

I launched

```
# yum install -y "perl(IO::Pty)"
No package perl(IO::Pty) available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

So, how to install all required perl modules to the RHEL?

Comment: try `cpan`. E.g. `cpan IO::Pty`.

Comment: The naming convention for RPMs of Perl modules is `perl-Module-Name`, so in this case, `perl-IO-Pty`. However, `yum` should take care of installing dependencies automatically, so I'm guessing there's no RPM for this module. Use `cpan` as Sobrique suggested.

Comment: Your `yum` command is correct. The RPM for IO::Pty should be perl-IO-Pty, but "perl(IO::Pty)" will be a feature that is provided by that RPM so your command should work. Trying it on my (Centos 5.8) system, I see that both perl-Expect and perl-IO-Pty are supplied by the EPEL repository. In order to help more, we'd need to know which version of RHEL you are using (`lsb_release -d`) and which yum repos you have configured (`yum repolist`).

Answer (score 1):

The `perl-IO-Tty` package is provided by the `rhel-7-server-optional-rpms`
repository.  It looks like the Optional repository is not enabled on your system. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843159/1640661) explains how to do so:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching for the each piece of the package with: `sudo yum search perl | grep IO | grep Pty`

return: perl-IO-Pty-Easy.noarch : Easy interface to IO::Pty

But, I used your code, minus `-y` in CentOS 7, and found the following:

```
$ sudo yum install "perl(IO::Pty)"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-IO-Tty.x86_64 0:1.10-11.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                       Arch                                     Version                                          Repository                                      Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 perl-IO-Tty                                   x86_64                                   1.10-11.el7                                      CentOS-Cache                                    42 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 42 k
Installed size: 76 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Make sure you have access to the default repositories and they are enabled...

Hope this helps,
Peter